# geth 1.8.8 miner hashrate 0 after join network where major miners ran on older version

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

I am planning to upgrade my miners from 1.7.x to 1.8.x.

For testing purposes, I've made a copy of geth's data and then I run a new version of the geth miner against my copied data. After the new miner finishes DAG generation, I waited to see the Hashrate of the new miner. Unfortunately, the new miner hashrate is always zero.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Using block explorer I can confirm that the new miner did mined some blocks. However, the fact it mines while hashrate is zero is inexplicable.

Comment: This seems to be something for a ticket, have you opened up an issue on github already ?